# Solving the equations of neutronic kinetic using Radau method from scipy.integrated at python

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I've tried to solve the system of equations of neutronic kinetic with two feedbacks (the fuel temperature feedback and the coolant temperature feedback) using RADAU method in python.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import Radau

def kin(x, t):
    beta = []
    lam = []
    lam = [0.001334, 0.032739, 0.12078, 0.30278, 0.84949, 2.853]
    beta = [0.000256, 0.00146, 0.001306, 0.002843, 0.000937, 0.000202]
    lifetime = 0.000015
    betasum = sum(beta)
    alfa_ttop = -0.000018
    alfa_ttn = -0.00026
    po0 = -1.0 * betasum
    n0 = 35.2 * 1000000
    Ttop0 = 377
    mtop = 1469.71
    ctop = 300
    kt = 11000
    Tvh = 271
    Gtn = 179.9
    ctn = 5500
    gamv = 900
    mtn = 500
    n = x[0]
    c1 = x[1]
    c2 = x[2]
    c3 = x[3]
    c4 = x[4]
    c5 = x[5]
    c6 = x[6]
    Ttop = x[7]
    Ttn = x[8]
    dndt = (po0 + alfa_ttop * (Ttop - Ttop0) + alfa_ttn * (Ttn - Tvh) - betasum) / lifetime * n + lam[0] * c1 + lam[1] * c2 + lam[2] * c3 + lam[3] * c4 + lam[4] * c5 + lam[5] * c6
    dc1dt = beta[0] / lifetime * n - lam[0] * c1
    dc2dt = beta[1] / lifetime * n - lam[1] * c2
    dc3dt = beta[2] / lifetime * n - lam[2] * c3
    dc4dt = beta[3] / lifetime * n - lam[3] * c4
    dc5dt = beta[4] / lifetime * n - lam[4] * c5
    dc6dt = beta[5] / lifetime * n - lam[5] * c6
    dTtopdt = 1.0 / (mtop * ctop) * (n - kt * (Ttop - Ttn))
    dTtndt = 1.0 / (mtn * ctn) * (kt * (Ttop - Ttn) - gamv * ctn * Gtn * (Ttn - Tvh))

   return (dndt, dc1dt, dc2dt, dc3dt, dc4dt, dc5dt, dc6dt, dTtopdt, dTtndt)


n0 = 35.2 * 1000000
beta = []
lam = []
lam = [0.001334, 0.032739, 0.12078, 0.30278, 0.84949, 2.853]
beta = [0.000256, 0.00146, 0.001306, 0.002843, 0.000937, 0.000202]
lifetime = 0.000015
Tvh = 271
Ttop0 = 377

x0 = np.array(
[n0, beta[0] * n0 / (lifetime * lam[0]), beta[1] * n0 / (lifetime * lam[1]), beta[2] * n0 / (lifetime * lam[2]),
 beta[3] * n0 / (lifetime * lam[3]), beta[4] * n0 / (lifetime * lam[4]), beta[5] * n0 / (lifetime * lam[5]), Ttop0,
 Tvh])
 t = np.linspace(0, 350, 700)
 t_bound = 700
 x = Radau(kin, t, x0, t_bound)

 n = x[:, 0]
 for i in range(0, len(n)):
    print(t[i], n[i] / 1000000)
```

And i received the next mistakes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Apps/untitled2/Scripts/RADAU.py", line 62, in <module>
    x = Radau(kin, t, x0, t_bound)
  File "D:\Apps\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\radau.py", line 288, in __init__
    super(Radau, self).__init__(fun, t0, y0, t_bound, vectorized)
  File "D:\Apps\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.direction = np.sign(t_bound - t0) if t_bound != t0 else 1
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What should i do in order to fix this mistakes?
P.S. First I've solved it using odeint in python, and it worked, but i found out that for this system of equations the odeint is not appropriate, because it is the stiff system of differential equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not explicitly said in the documentation, but `Radau` is just the stepper class for the method, the return of a successful call to this constructor is a stepper object. To get a result similar to `odeint` use the general interface method

```
sol = solve_ivp(kin, (t[0],t[-1]), x0, t_eval=t, max_step=max_step, method='Radau', atol=atol, rtol=rtol)
x = sol.y
```

- `kin` has the argument order `t,x`,
- `max_step` has to take the role of `t_bound` to limit how far into the future the ODE is evaluated, compatible with your values would be `max_step=350`,
- it is my recommendation to always explicitly control the tolerances, especially to adapt the absolute tolerance to the expected scale of the state vector,
- the output is also transpose to the output of `odeint`, `sol.y[j,k]` is component `j` at time index `k`.

Comment: thank you, it works, and it gave me the same result as the 'odeint' method. But i've thought that this result is wrong, and it is wrong because of the using 'odeint' method . I found an article which explains that odeint is not appropriate for solving the stiff  ODE systems. And i've thought that Radau method will help me to receive another solution, but i received the same as in the odeint method. So,maybe it doesn't depend on what method we chose... Nevertheless, thank you for helping me!

Comment: `odeint` also uses implicit methods and is thus more suitable for stiff problems than explicit methods like `RK45`. There might be some problems where one method performs better than the other, which you would measure in the number of function evaluations under the same error tolerances. Failure of the method due to stiffness is indicated by the step size being steered to zero, leading to "excessive work done" or underflow errors or warnings from the solver, that is, `t+dt` does not move (sufficiently) away from `t` .